# UIButton + XIB subviews = no highlight

Tags: uibutton, touch, xib, subview, effect

I have a UIButton and this button loads a subview from an xib. 
Everything is drawn fine and the delegate method is called correctly but there's no highlight effect.

I have everything on the xib set as userInteractionEnabled=false. 
If I remove those subviews, the highlight effect works again.

Answer (score 6):

If all your subviews happen to be images, there is a crazy solution: create multiple UIButtons as subviews and tie their highlight / disabled states together. Add them all as subviews of a master button, disable user interaction, and use a K-V observer on the master button. Here's a quick example:

```
// Only perform the addObserver part if from a XIB
- (UIButton *) makeMasterButton { 
    // Create some buttons
    UIButton *masterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    masterButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

    UIButton *slaveButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    slaveButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [slaveButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Top.png"]];
    slaveButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,100,50);
    [masterButton addSubview:slaveButton1];

    UIButton *slaveButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    slaveButton2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [slaveButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bottom.png"]];
    slaveButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,100,50);
    [masterButton addSubview:slaveButton2];

    // Secret sauce: add a K-V observer
    [masterButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    [masterButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"enabled" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    return masterButton;
}

 ...

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)object;
        for (id subview in button.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                UIButton *buttonSubview = (UIButton *) subview;
                buttonSubview.highlighted = button.highlighted;
                buttonSubview.enabled = button.enabled;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had to do this once when I wanted to have an "image" for a UIButton that had layers, transparency and dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the view you've loaded from the xib into a UIImage and add that image to the UIButton instead. This way the highlight will be shown when the button is pressed:

```
UIButton *button;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewFromXib.frame.size);
[viewFromXib.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```